# Extract number with special characters from a file using sed and grep command

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I am trying to extract the number surrounded by the square brackets after matching with the word that is placed after the number. for ex.

The file contains

```
xxxx [098] yyyy zzzz
```

I need to search for the yyyy and if it is matches in the line, i have to extract the 098 itself.

I am trying with

```
sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g' str.txt
```

for extracting the number without pattern matching.

and am using

```
sed -nr 's/.*( |^)([0-9]+) yyyy.*/\2/p' str.txt
```

for pattern match and get the number that is placed before that match. But i couldn't merge this two commands. I am confusing with the error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unknown option to `s'

I think this held because of using the / as the delimiter more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to use the conditional print logic for such cases where you you decide to *print* on a condition. With the `-n` and `p` predicates, you can control the command to print the matched group only if the match was successful.

So combining your attempts you need something like

```
sed -n 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\][[:space:]]yyyy.*/\1/p'
```

which won't print for any other case other than `yyyy` after the `[..]` string.

But parsing a space de-limited file is quite easy if you decide to use `awk` in which your result could simply be written as

```
awk '$3 == "yyyy" { gsub(/[][]/,"",$2); print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged grep, another option if you can use gnu grep is to make use of the `-P` option `Perl-compatible regular expression` and use lookarounds:

```
grep -Po "(?<=\[)\d+(?=\] yyyy)" str.txt
```

That will give you `098`

Comment: Thanks !. It worked great. Thanks for suggesting -P option. will explore more about this.

Answer (score 0):

if data in 'd' tried on gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/.*xxxx\s*\[(098)\]\s*yyyy.*/\1/' d
```